# SSRS scheduled reports not working

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My scheduled reports in SQL server won't run. I checked the logs and found the job that was failing. The error message in the log was:

> 'EXECUTE AS LOGIN' failed for the requested login 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK 
>   SERVICE'. The step failed.

I'm using SQL authentication for the report so it shouldn't be issues with the permissions to the data. No sheduled reports on the server will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:
http://www.themssforum.com/SVCS/Unable-execute/

Apperently there was something wrong with the login for 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' and it wouldn't run the jobs it owned properly. Anyone understand why this might have happened?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the permissions for your Network Service account?  Specifically make sure they have the "Act as part of the OS" permission.  If I'm reading the error message correctly, it looks like the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account failed to execute as a logged on user. It doesn't look like it ever got to the query, looks like it's failing in the Windows authentication portion, so never gets to the SQL authentication piece.

You might also check the Security Event Log in Windows.  If it is an authentication problem, there might be additional information logged by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you hit the Web Service page (ReportService2005.asmx) for SRS with a web browser? If not, it might point to the SRS service, if you can, it might point to the scheduler service.

Answer (score 0):

Just to troubleshoot, can you use a domain account rather than the builtin NetworkService account to run your service?

I also found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.sqlserver.reportingsvcs&tid=ca2a5bdd-93a8-48d6-a675-ffea355dbac1&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) post that describes the same error you reported:

Maybe that solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remeber having a similar problem a long time ago, the problem was related to accessing the smtp server to despatch the reports and was resolved by applying a patch to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you are running a non-english operating system.

Somehow, for whatever reasons, the login name for the network service is sometimes localized when the OS is translated into other languages.

Now a lot of programs expect the login name to be hard coded to "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" - in a German version of Windows for example the name of the account is "NT-AUTORITÄT\NETZWERKDIENST". So your program is looking for the english name, can't find it, and shows an error.

Even some Microsoft programs run into this trap and show errors like this when installed!